# Gmail-style spellcheck for CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

How can I implement Gmail-style spellcheck for CKeditor field? Are there any open source or free plugins for this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there are any plug-ins for it, if there are google will find them for you I think..

I do know that TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor supports spellcheck.